# How do I set up Firebase Auth in my Flutter App for multiple organizations?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter

I designed an app and all the auth is done with Firebase along with storing documents. I have everything working perfectly but the app right now is set up for one database.

This will not work because The app will be used by multiple organizations who will have their own users and data which should be separated in another database? My question is how do I go about setting my Flutter App and Firebase to handle multiple organizations.

I just don't understand how the login page in the app would know what database to log in to. It would have to somehow be connected to the user.

Any push in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately as of now, Firebase is not well suited for multi-tenant apps which is what I believe you're referring to. Technically, you can have a completely separate app for each client that ties to their own Firebase, but that's not an ideal solution. I am marking this as duplicate as the topic of multi-tenant solutions has been asked, discussed and answered many times.

Answer (score 0):

If this a commercial app you are developing and customising for your customers, where each company supposed to have their own circle of users, you should always separate the database as well as the codebase (project), for various reasons which include potential data breaches, privacy etc. As a responsible and accountable developer, avoid reusing the same infrastructure for multiple customers.

If this is just a normal app that behaves like those apps we downloaded from the app store, then it shouldn't be a problem as Firebase Auth can handle it. Just apply the Firebase Security Rules to restrict the content.

Comment: While the intent here is good, Firebase is not designed to handle multi-tenancy and [Rules are Not Filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters) so using rules is not a solution.

Comment: @Jay My second paragraph refers to the casual app, where we treat each user as an equal individual.

Comment: Thank you both for the input and the push in the right direction.

Comment: @AngusTay Understood which is why I didn't downvote the answer as it's generally correct and helpful. However, the OP clearly states *The app will be used by multiple organizations who will have their own users and data* which is a multi-tenant app and I don't want them to thinking they can use Rules to filter different companies data to prevent crossover.